# A day with $c=500$ Km/H

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, everyday-life, physical-constants

I was reading paradoxes and was doing some problems with unexpected answers on Special relativity. And I find special relativity to be crazy. Sometimes It's hard even to believe these things due to the Newtonian mindset. I find it's good that $c$ has such enormous value that is $3\times 10^{8} $ m/s.

But for the moment consider that $c$ has a value that is not such big. I decided to take it $500$ km/H, not too high. Can anyone give me a glimpse of How the world be like? So any summarize the major changes, and give the summary of the day, in the world with $c$ to be small so that effect is much larger.

---

For this pretend everything to be inertial so that we can neglect the effect of general relativity.

Comment: I can recommend the novelles by physicist George Gamow about Mr. Tompkins dream adventures https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr_Tompkins. There Gamow describes exactly what you are asking to - what if the physical constants of nature, such as the speed of light, the Plank constant etc. were different.

Comment: Various physical constants depend on $c$. How are they affected?